# Jaws shortcut key to shift focus to the Search term occurrence from JAWS find dialog

Tags: accessibility

When I use JAWS 'find' to locate some terms on a web page, I use F3 and Shift+F3 to to move to next and previous instances of search term occurrences. The terms get read by JAWS however the focus doesn't move to each search term by default.
What I want to know is whether there's a shortcut to shift focus to the occurrence like for example, browser native 'find' starts highlighting the search term occurrences and pressing Esc shifts focus to the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your definition of "focus".  When you use F3, JAWS will read the result of the find and its surrounding context.  The JAWS virtual focus **is** moved to the search result.  If you use the up/down arrow keys after hitting F3, you'll hear the next or previous element (respectively) in the DOM relative to the search result, so the "focus" is moved.

However, if you're talking about the focus as in the keyboard focus, no, that is not changed.  If the search result were in a paragraph (`<p>`), the keyboard focus would not be able to move to that element unless it had `tabindex="0"` or `tabindex="-1"`.